# Cheking if form of submited email is correct

Tags: javascript, mysql, forms, validation, email

I've created this script to check form of email user will enter into textbox

```
function checkEmail() {

  var mail = document.getElementById('mail');
  var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/; /* regex        koda najdena na codeproject.com*/

  if (!filter.test(mail.value)) 
{
    alert('enter valid email');
    mail.focus;
    return false;
}
```

It's used to check form in this script and suposed to show you alert, before you are able to continue

```
<?php
    $flag = 0;
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {   
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if (!$con){
          die("cannot connect: " . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db("strek", $con); 

        $nar_db="SELECT * FROM narocniki;";  
        $result = mysql_query($nar_db, $con);

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            if($_POST['mail']==$row['mail'])
                $flag = 1;
        }
        if($flag==0)
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO narocniki (mail)  VALUE ('$_POST[mail]')"; 
            mysql_query($sql, $con);    
            mysql_close($con);
            ?>
              <p align="center" class="vsebina" >
                Tvoj mail je bil uspešno sprejet!</p>    
            <p align="center"><a href="dogodki.php"><input type="button" name="return" value="nazaj"></a></p>
            <?php
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<p align="center" class="vsebina">Naveden mail je že v bazi naročnikov!</p>';
            ?>
            <p align="center"><a href="dogodki.php"><input type="button" name="return" value="nazaj"></a></p>
            <?php
        }
    }
    else
    {
        include("vsebina/tabdog.html");
    ?>
         <p align="center" class="vsebina" id="mail">
      naroči se na najnovejše novice</p>

        <form action="dogodki.php" method="post">
            <p align="center" class="vsebina">vnesi svoj e-naslov:  <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" required>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="potrdi" onClick="return checkEmail()">  

            </p>
        </form>
    <?php
    }
  ?>
```

It's probably just something missing
Should I rather just include script inside the code, and where would be the best to place it-weather directly in head or rather somewhere in between

Is this even possible in my code, because it already checks if mail exists in database, and would then also need to check the form of email

Comment: are you calling `checkEmail` function on form submit

Comment: @DipeshParmar He's calling it from the onclick handler of the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it in the `onclick` attribute of the submit button, try doing it in the `onsubmit` attribute of the form:

```
<form action="dogodki.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkEmail()">
```

Comment: nope, the result is exactly the same
tried to keep it also in submit button and tried to replace it with onclick, but it's the same