# Alert problems with mail checking script

Tags: javascript, email, testing, filter, alert

In my short script, that is checking if submited email is in the right form, I always recive alert, no matter what I put in the form (email)

```
function checkEmail() {

  var mail = document.getElementById('mail');
  var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/; 

  if (!filter.test(mail.value)) 
  {
    alert('Prosimo, vnesite veljaven email');
    mail.focus;
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not related to your actual issue, but your regex is invalid for a number of the new TLDs, for example .museum. There are no doubt quite a few other types of addresses it also won't work with.

Comment: Can you post your HTML too?

Comment: Aside from @AdrianWragg's note, this works ok [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uNfph/). Note that it should be `mail.focus();` instead of `mail.focus;`.

Comment: the whole code is here already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649408/cheking-if-form-of-submited-email-is-correct
I tried to change all kind of miscelenious already, but the problem seems to be something bigger (or  something really bizzare)

Comment: thank you everyone for your help
I just changed my code with some from w3schools and rearanged it, so it works now
it can now also accept emails with other endings, like '.museum' so @AdrianWragg, thank you for that notice
if anyone need's it, code is here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp (scroll down)